# $.getScript not working rails 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Everything seems to work fine apart from the `$.getScript("/comments.js` part. I have tried to fix it but with no luck.

I have my `application.js` file which has:

```
$(function() {
setTimeout(test, 1000);

});

function test () {

$.getScript("/comments.js")
setTimeout(test, 1000);
}
$.getScript("/comments.js", function(){

 updateComments();
});
```

and my index.js.erb in the views/comments

```
function  updateComments(){
  alert("testing");
    }
```

my comments controller

```
def index
# ...
end
```

layouts/application.html.erb

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag  "application"  %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

I am just trying to see if I can get it to work but it just does nothing.

Comment: are you using asset pipeline?, in that case I think is a route problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to use any method from the script which you are loading using `getScript` then wait untill the script is loaded. Use its callback method which will be called once the script is loaded on the page. Try this.

```
$.getScript("/comments.js", function(){
     //Write your code here
     updateComments();
});
```

Also make sure the path of the js file is correct.